# How to check two condition in single query in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Example

```
------------------------------------------
Amount     |   Type
------------------------------------------
1000       | credit
------------------------------------------
4500       | credit
------------------------------------------
1250       | debit
------------------------------------------
500        |  credit
------------------------------------------


select IFNULL(SUM(amount),0) as Credit_Amount,IFNULL(SUM(amount),0) as Debit_Amount, 
type,party from receipt where  party='$list[id]' and type='credit' or 
type='debit'
```

> Output

```
Credit_Amount = 6000
Debit_Amount = 1250
```

Here if the type is credit the value should add with `credit` variable and if type is debit the value should add with `debit`. Please hep me to solve this Problem.

Comment: From your description, it is unclear what needs to be added to what. Can you provide sample data and results?

Comment: Please create fiddle

Answer (score 2):

this is query for credit only you can append as per requirement.

```
Select IF(type='Credit', SUM(amount), null) as Credit from receipt
```